# DirectAdmin php api creating users

Tags: php, api, sockets, curl

I want create php script witch will be able create users in DirectAdmin, for this is command 
`/CMD_API_ACCOUNT_USER`:

```
`MyServer.com:2222/CMD_API_ACCOUNT_USER?action=create&add=submit....`
```

But, to theresseler(admin) must be logged in. I don't know how to do this, please suggest what use to login:

`socket`, `curl` or something else.

Comment: I'm sorry about the "kick". But i'm also struggling with this problem. Did you solved it ? If so can you post an answer? here, have a +1.

Answer (score 0):

DA uses the HTTP Basic Auth to login your account.

Here is a official document
https://www.directadmin.com/api.php

Comment: Direct links to documentation aren't good answers. Please put a little more details into future answers so that a user can actually understand the solution to the problem based primarily off your answer.